# Salesforce Flow Record Triggered Scheduled Paths

Tags: visual-workflow, scheduled-job

I have a record triggered Flow that I would like to schedule a future field update with, and also have an immediate update run to toggle a switch back to an 'off' position.

When I have an Update Records node in the 'Run Immediately' path, the other scheduled path (which is set to run 5 minutes after the initial record update) does not run. If I have nothing in the 'Run Immediately' path, then the scheduled path works as normal.

Basically my question is: can a record triggered flow run the 'Run Immediately' path and another scheduled path in the same transaction? I have not been able to find anything that addresses this question, and currently it looks like either it isn't supported, is bugged, or my error.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I figured it out. My 'Run Immediately' field update was changing a field that was initially in the entry criteria for the flow. As soon as the entry criteria was not met, the scheduled path was removed.